# What does "conditionalities" mean in this article from The Hindu?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/lead/reimagining-the-niti-aayog/article28118992.ece - In this article, I did not understand what "conditionalities" meant in the following sentence from the 6th paragraph:

*In short, the NITI Aayog should be engaged with the allocation of “transformational” capital in a formulaic manner, complete with incentive-compatible **conditionalities**.*

My understanding is that it means that the organization NITI Aayog should incorporate measures that could be conditionally applied and that could be incentivised. Can someone help me to clarify the meaning?

Comment: Hello, Ananya. Perhaps if you wrote to them and hinted that you had quite a bit to invest if they could explain their strange use of language ...?

Comment: Hello, Edwin. As a matter of fact, I did comment on this article asking the same but the comments get reviewed first, and mine hasn't been posted up yet..

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionality) gives a basic definition of  _conditionality_, but that doesn't help with the actual details of exactly who imposes exactly what.

Comment: Yes, dictionary definition was the first thing I looked up too, and tried to fit a meaning to it, but couldn't. I will have to make do with what I think they mean till, hopefully, someone understands this strange usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me as if 'conditionalities' is being used here as a fancy term for 'conditions'.

'Incentive-compatible' is being used as an adjective. This adjective suggests perhaps that the conditions should be favourable and offer incentives.

Comment: Okay, thank you, @tom. I understand that conditions should offer incentives, but how do I understand favorable? Do they imply so when they say "incentive-compatible"?

Comment: It means that the there should be a properly defined and consistent (*formulaic*) system for allocating *transformational capital*, and that the conditions on which transformational capital is allocated should be compatible with incentivising whatever transformation it is they are trying to bring about - in that sense they should be *favourable*.

Comment: 'Looks to me ...' almost always gets my downvote. Please check at the Help Center about respectable answers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - point taken and answer edited. Thanks for the gentle rebuke.

Comment: I read 'incentive-compatible' as meaning 'avoiding dis-incentives' rather than 'providing extra incentives'.

Comment: @BoldBen - that may be correct. In my opinion it is hard to know exactly what is meant here without more context or other background information.

Comment: Ahhhhhh. hhh. The point is that answers lacking authoritative references almost always come across as mere opinion. And they can be mere opinion. The Help Center expressly advocates well researched answers.